# Android Spinner: how to fade background (activity layout) when the Spinner pop-up is displayed?

Tags: android, background, spinner

By default it looks like the Spinner does not fade the underneath activity layout when the pop-up with the list of choices is displayed.

The DialogFragment fades the underneath activity automatically, I want to have the same behaviour for all my spinner instances.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I found the answer myself: there is a method [setAlpha()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29) in the class View.

It just needs to be bind to the Spinner click events